# Problems with a complex table

Tags: tables, multirow

I am having troubles creating a complex table. I am basically a noob, this is the first time I deal with not very easy tables.

I would like to get something like:

```
 _________________________________________________________
|                                                         |
|                 Methodology for A and B                 |
|                      two lines text                     |
|_________________________________________________________|
|        Methods with A      |     Methods with B         | <-- evenly distributed and centered in the cell, the two column must have the same size (the page size in total)
|____________________________|____________________________|      
|                            |                            |       
|                            | Method B1                  |       
| Method A1                  |____________________________|      
|                            |                            |       
|____________________________| Method B2                  |       
|                            |____________________________|    
|                            |                            |
| Method A2                  | Method B3                  |
|    - name 1                |    - name 3                |
|    - name 2                |    - name 4                |
|____________________________|    - name 5                |
|                            |____________________________|     
|                            |              |             | <-- evenly distributed and centered. The two multi-row must have the same size        
| Method A3                  |              | Method B4.1 |        
|    - name 6                |              |    - name 8 | 
|    - name 7                |              |    - name 9 |       
|                            |              |             |        
|                            | Method B4    |_____________|        
|                            |              |             |        
|                            |              | Method B4.1 |        
|                            |              |    - name 10|       
|____________________________|              |    - name 11|  
|                            |______________|_____________|
|                            |                            |
|                            | Method B5                  |
|                            |    - name 12               |
|  Method A4                 |    - name 13               |
|     - name 14              |                            |
|     - name 15              |____________________________|
|     - name 16              |                            |
|                            | Method B6                  |
|                            |    - name 17               |
|                            |    - name 18               |
|____________________________|____________________________| 
   ^                                ^
  always aligned on the left and centered in the cell
  the real text inside sometimes could big slightly bigger and might have to go on a second line
```

**EDIT**: I have tried to get the results by using the minipage environment, which has also a good looking outcome. However I still need to improve the results.

```
\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\smallskip
{\centering\Large\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Methodology for A and B, two lines text}}\par}

\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep-\fboxrule)}%
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Methods for A}
\end{center}

\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule
\textbf{Methods for A1}

\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\textbf{Methods for A2}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-20pt]
\item[--] name 1
\item[--] name 2
\end{itemize}

\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\textbf{Methods for A3}

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-20pt]
\item[--] name 3
\item[--] name 4
\end{itemize}

\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\textbf{Methods for A4}

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-20pt]
\item[--] name 5
\item[--] name 6
\item[--] name 7
\end{itemize}
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\vrule width\fboxrule\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep-\fboxrule)}%
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Methods for B}
\end{center}

\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\textbf{Methods B1}

\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\textbf{Methods B2}

\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\textbf{Methods B3}

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-20pt]
\item[--] name 8
\item[--] name 9
\item[--] name 10
\end{itemize}
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule


\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep-\fboxrule)}%

\textbf{Methods B4}

\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule
\end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep-\fboxrule)}%

\textbf{Methods B4.1}

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-20pt]
\item[--] name 11
\item[--] name 12
\end{itemize}
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule
\bigskip
\textbf{Methods B4.2}

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-20pt]
\item[--] name 13
\item[--] name 14
\end{itemize}
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip

\end{minipage}%

\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\textbf{Methods B5}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-20pt]
\item[--] name 15
\item[--] name 16
\end{itemize}
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\hrule height\fboxrule

\textbf{Methods B6}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-20pt]
\item[--] name 17
\item[--] name 18
\end{itemize}

\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip

\end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}}
```

So I still have problems in the spacing and centering of the "boxes" and especially for the box of Methods B4.1 and B4.2.

I am completely lost, please help! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please have a look at `multirow` and `\multicolumn`.

Comment: Also, I would make two tables side by side.

Comment: Look at this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245623/issues-with-a-complex-table  I think this is exactly what you want.

Comment: Not sure what I have done is the best way, but still I am starting getting something similar to what I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have started working from that question, but could only manage to partially solve the problem. Thanks!